# Recursive listing directories - generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator

I want to create method to list recursively paths on generators (so i don't have to wait for output, in case of large directories). The code I have created, goes deep in filed hierarchy, however doesn't come back :( What am I doing wrong here?

e.g.:

```
- /

-- a

--- aa

---- aaa

---- aab

--- ab

-- b
```

Code will go like, `a, aa, aaa, aab` - I am missing `aab` and `b` and so on

NOTES:

1) Code is not ready, so naming is improper, i'll fix that when code will work as intended

2) method `self.list` is also a generator, that lists directory in remote svn, and yields paths

```
def list_recursive(self, excluded_paths=[], rel_path=''):
    print('rel_path: '+rel_path)
    for path in self.list(rel_path=rel_path):
        yield path
        a = rel_path + path
        print('\ta: ' + a)
        if a.endswith('/'):
            print('\ta: ' + a)
            for aaa in self.list_recursive(rel_path=a):
                yield(aaa)
```

Comment: Wont work on remote repositories. We do not have those files on our OS

Comment: Well one thing you're doing wrong is not posting a proper MCVE.

Comment: Well, tat is because I have no test repo to show... basically the self.list is 'ls' command, but for remote repository, that yields every line. Adding that to code would probably cause you to focus on unneeded part (e.g. someone proposed os.walk, that i cannot use there).

Answer (score 0):

I've found an error, in line `for path in self.list(rel_path=rel_path):`. It should be `for path in list(self.list(rel_path=rel_path)):` as in recurrence, for went just to first directory and list didn't have all others. List has full list of files in that dir, so for loop can return to them.